# Use Swift Package with multiple branch requirements

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

In my app, I link a Swift Package (let's alias it as **Package1**) that has 2 branches: `main` and `custom-branch`.
Additionally, I link another Swift Package (**Package2**) that depends on **Package1** on branch `main`.

In the app, I want to link **Package1** on branch `custom-branch`, but if I do it, Xcode complains while resolving the packages with the following error:

> **Package1** is required using two different revision-based requirements (main and custom-branch), which is not supported

What could be a solve for this, or alternatively, a workaround?

Comment: Are "main" and "custom-branch" that much different? Can't they be on the same branch, but two different subpackages? Like "Core", "Option1" (main) & "Option2" (custom-branch), while "Option1" uses Core & Option2 uses Core too?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting approach, but I'm not sure I fully understood your explanation regarding the subpackages. Mind sharing an example or elaborating a bit?

Comment: For instance SDWebImage does it: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/blob/master/Package.swift it has `SDWebImage`, and `SDWebImageMapKit` which depends on `SDWebImage`. Firebase too (but since it's bigger, the example is quite complexe), etc. Depending on your package, it can be a core and an "extension", or a core and two "extensions"...